# No token for microk8s dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I use Rocky Linux 8 and installed micro8ks with Snap. I tried to enable the dashboard of microk8s according to this docu:
https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dashboard

```
microk8s enable dashboard
token=$(microk8s kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep default-token | cut -d " " -f1)
microk8s kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $token
```

But the last command does not print out any token. It gives this:

```
Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-certs
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
csrf:  256 bytes


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
priv:  1679 bytes
pub:   459 bytes
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that with kubernetes version 1.24 the token for service accounts are no longer generated automatically.